# IF THEN ELSE statement on excel vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i need a little help on how i can adjust my macro that search's and selects a worksheet "sheet9" and continues with the macro...

some times that worksheet is not created in the workbook

so here i need help on the syntax on how it should be?

```
''''''''''''''''''' example not valid macro!! ''''''''''''''''''''''
Search worksheet "sheet9" in active workbook 
if "sheet9" not found then create.worksheet"sheet9"
ELSE 
sheets("sheet9").select
```

hope that makes sense

1. START
2. SEARCH for worksheet "sheet9"
3. IF worksheet "sheet9" NOT FOUND
4. THEN CREATE worksheet "sheet9"
5. ELSE select worksheet "sheet9" IF FOUND
6. END

Comment: Type [`test if sheet exists vba` in google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=test%20if%20sheet%20exists%20vba), you will get a mountain of ways to do this.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php

Comment: It looks like your code mistake was putting `create.worksheet"sheet9"` on the same line as `then`

Comment: that's not a valid macro

Comment: Guys I think he was using pseudo code, to try and explain better how he thinks it should work, not actually saying this is the code I am trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to look for and then create or select the worksheet

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim bFound As Boolean
bFound = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name = "sheet9" Then
            bFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws

    If bFound Then
        Sheets("sheet9").Select
    Else
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        ws.Name = "sheet9"
        ws.Select
    End If
```

Comment: @Mohammed You tried to edit the post stating that you received an error of Cant assign to read only property.  This example is valid and does what it is intended to do, Look for the sheet and create it.  You may want to post your code with the edits to determine why you received that error.

Comment: sorry so what happens if "sheet9" is already in the workbook and can not create the same worksheet name?

Comment: @Mohammed you need to post your code as that is a valid snippit and does what is intended and has been tested multiple times .

Comment: this worked PERFECTLY .. Thank you @Sorceri your a star

Answer (score 2):

You *could* search for the sheet and then decide what to do or you could just try to select it and if there is an error then create it:

```
Sub Sheet9()
    On Error GoTo Create
    Worksheets("Sheet9").Select
    Exit Sub
Create:
    Worksheets.Add.Name = "Sheet9"
End Sub
```